# Android Animation confusion

Tags: android

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(
        0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation1
        .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation1.setDuration(1000);
rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(10);

imageLoad.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
imageLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
loadText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

encryptButton
        .setImageResource(R.drawable.button_encrypt);

myThread thread= new myThread();
myThread.start();

thread.join();

imageLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
loadText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

myThread sleeps and does nothing else. Then I join it in the main thread.

However the animation displays after the thread joins for some reason.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Never join on the UI thread, it blocks the UI thread until the other thread is done.

Comment: How does the animation work. The text is set invisible before the animation finishes.

Comment: You can set a listener on the animation to know when it ends. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener)